# How to fix the getter length was called on null in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I'm getting the NoSuchMethodError: The gettter 'length' was called on null so just wondering how to fix this issue.

The issue happend when I try to get the length of the favorite value.

Favorite View Model

```
class FavoriteViewModel extends BaseViewModel {
  List<FavoriteModel> favorites = [];   

  void initialize(FavoriteService favProvider) {
    favorites = favProvider.getFavorites();
  }
}
```

Reorder Screen

```
class _ReorderPageState extends State<ReorderPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var favProvider = Provider.of<FavoriteService>(context, listen: true);
    return BaseView<FavoriteViewModel>(onModelReady: (model) {
      model.initialize(favProvider);
    }, builder: (context, model, child) {
      return model.state == ViewState.Busy
......


  Widget reorderWidget(FavoriteViewModel model, BuildContext bcontext) {
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.transparent),
      child: ReorderableListView(
        onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
          _onParentReorder(oldIndex, newIndex, model);
        },
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        children: List.generate(
          model.favorites.length,    // I think the issue is in this line
          (index) {
            FavoriteModel favorite = model.favorites[index]; // I think the issue is in this line
```

Comment: This is almost always an indication of not managing a Future properly.  Many answers to this very thing have been answered here. Please search "flutter called on null".

Answer (score 1):

Did you already try to use elvis operator (similar to typescript and kotlin) ?

```dart
model?.favorites?.length
```

and also, its possible in your viewModel initializer `favProvider.getFavorites()` is always null ??